# Visiting edges, vertices in an undirected graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm, depth-first-search

Problem: You have an Undirected graph `G = (V, E)` (V = vertices, E = edges) and you must visit each vertex and pass each edge in both directions.

The only algorithms I know for graphs are DFS, BFS, and a few MST's (Kruskal, etc.) My friend and I were discussing this problem, if it were directed I would simply DFS, and then DFS the transpose but the graph is unfortunately undirected. My friend proposed we perform an MST and DFS the MST and then find the remaining edges by iterating through those that arent in MST. I sort of see what he means but I am not sure this is a good approach? opinions? Also, how would I be able to pass by an edge in both directions if it is undirected?

Comment: You can use either DFS or BFS, it won't matter; with DFS; just think of the backtracking as passing the edge in reverse direction, and with BFS, you'll need to backtrack recursively, starting with the set of vertices from which you discovered the final frontier.

Comment: Regarding an MST: those do not hold all edges of the graph they span in the general case, which can easily be proven by the fact that a tree over n vertices has n-1 edges, so the MST (or any ST) of a graph that has more than n-1 edges will not have all the edges of the graph, so operating on an MST will not help you.

Comment: @G.Bach I think you are right. both DFS and BFS will traverse all edges and vertices but MST does not help here.

Comment: @jurgenreza He wants to pass all edges in both directions (though I'm not sure what "passing" an edge in an algorithm actually means); DFS/BFS without modification won't consider edges in both directions while calculating the next frontier.

Comment: Can you clarify a bit? If the goal is actually to find a path that visits every vertex at least once and every edge in both directions at least once, then you can take your approach. If that is not the goal, just iterate over the graph's edges and vertices without restricting yourself to Graph Traversal. What is is it that you really want to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter if the graph is directed or undirected. You could just replace every undirected edge with two directed edges and perform whatever algorithm you have for a directed graph. Both DFS and BFS will traverse the whole vertices and edges.

I think what you are looking for is called [Graph Traversal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_traversal). BFS and DFS are two graph traversal algorithms and they do not require the graph to be directed. MST on the other hand, is not a graph traversal algorithm.